# ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: 500 Internal Server Error: Cannot start container : [9] System error: not a directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

i added config file for kibana "- ./kibana/config/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml" it's working fine in my local test machine (without swarm cluster),. but on swarm getting "ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: 500 Internal Server Error: Cannot start container 3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530: [9] System error: not a directory" error.

my local storege driver is AUFS but at cluster the driver for each node is devicemapper. do i need to use AUFS for what could be the reason for this issue. or should i use some tool like flocker.

i added my docker-compose config, swarm info and error for verbose dump.

`ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: 500 Internal Server Error: Cannot start container 3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530: [9] System error: not a directory`

`version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    build: elasticsearch/
    command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  logstash:
    build: logstash/
    command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
    extra_hosts:
      - ${MONGO}
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d
  kibana:
    build: kibana/
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
  nginx:
    build: nginx/
    depends_on:
          - elasticsearch
          - kibana
    extra_hosts:
          - "es.imoney.my:127.0.0.1"
          - "reports.imoney.my:127.0.0.1"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
networks:
  default:
    driver: overlay
volumes: {}`

`Containers: 6
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 17
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 2
 report-node-1: 10.130.3.39:2375
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 3
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 8
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 16.45 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=4.4.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-02-12T04:26:24Z
 report-node-2: 10.130.0.114:2375
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 3
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 8
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 16.45 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=4.4.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-02-12T04:26:20Z
Plugins: 
 Volume: 
 Network: 
Kernel Version: 4.4.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 16
Total Memory: 32.91 GiB
Name: 455a1ddf13bf`

`compose.service.build_container_labels: Added config hash: 4360ff02d2c79d27ddef844b2823c0f563bfa8ac13c127b2186fbbb5f7b1db7e
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker create_host_config <- (memswap_limit=None, links=[], devices=None, pid_mode=None, log_config={'Type': u'', 'Config': {}}, cpu_quota=None, read_only=None, dns=None, volumes_from=[], port_bindings={}, security_opt=None, extra_hosts=None, cgroup_parent=None, network_mode=u'dockerkibana_default', cap_add=None, restart_policy=None, dns_search=None, privileged=False, binds=[u'/home/ariful/docker-kibana/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml:rw'], ipc_mode=None, mem_limit=None, cap_drop=None, ulimits=None)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker create_host_config -> {'Binds': [u'/home/ariful/docker-kibana/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml:rw'],
 'Links': [],
 'LogConfig': {'Config': {}, 'Type': u''},
 'NetworkMode': u'dockerkibana_default',
 'PortBindings': {},
 'VolumesFrom': []}
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker create_container <- (name=u'dockerkibana_kibana_1', image=u'dockerkibana_kibana', labels={u'com.docker.compose.service': u'kibana', u'com.docker.compose.project': u'dockerkibana', u'com.docker.compose.config-hash': '4360ff02d2c79d27ddef844b2823c0f563bfa8ac13c127b2186fbbb5f7b1db7e', u'com.docker.compose.version': u'1.6.0', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff': u'False', u'com.docker.compose.container-number': '1'}, host_config={'NetworkMode': u'dockerkibana_default', 'Links': [], 'PortBindings': {}, 'Binds': [u'/home/ariful/docker-kibana/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml:rw'], 'LogConfig': {'Type': u'', 'Config': {}}, 'VolumesFrom': []}, environment={u'affinity:container': u'=0bf65d0d5bcebf1ad106556b46c32b2d4c0dad49f91b4a41fde9d8563423ef4c'}, volumes={u'/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml': {}}, detach=True)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker create_container -> {u'Id': u'3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530'}
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'/tmp/entrypoint.sh'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': [u'/tmp/entrypoint.sh'],
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'/docker-entrypoint.sh'],
             u'Env': [u'PATH=/opt/kibana/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
                      u'TINI_VERSION=v0.9.0',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'/tmp/entrypoint.sh'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': [u'/tmp/entrypoint.sh'],
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'/docker-entrypoint.sh'],
             u'Env': [u'PATH=/opt/kibana/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
                      u'TINI_VERSION=v0.9.0',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach <- (u'3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530', stderr=True, stream=True, stdout=True)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach -> <generator object _multiplexed_response_stream_helper at 0x7f92b781b4b0>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker disconnect_container_from_network <- (u'3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530', u'dockerkibana_default')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker disconnect_container_from_network -> None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker connect_container_to_network <- (u'3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530', u'dockerkibana_default', links=[], aliases=['kibana', u'3bf3e9b086'])
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker connect_container_to_network -> None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start <- (u'3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530')
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: 500 Internal Server Error: Cannot start container 3bf3e9b086b80b47e9cc055581ae005d41133187e4c6820cf34ba9ed580d4530: [9] System error: not a directory`